# connect to websocket with proxy in Deno

Tags: websocket, proxy, deno, ws

I want to connect to a Websocket with a Proxy and all of that using Deno. But sadly, I cannot find any Deno module that supports that. I even looked in the Nodejs websockets module and how it's handled there. But I don't really understand the standard deno websocket module, so I can't figure out how to implement proxies. Can someone help me?

Edit:

I found this:

`import { createRequire } from "https://deno.land/std/node/module.ts";`

`const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);`

Which lets me import node modules. So i can hopefully just use the node websocket module in Deno. I will update my Question if I can get it to work.

Comment: This is an interesting question IMO — and your reasons aren't (dis)qualifying criteria for question validity — but I'm curious why you want to proxy a websocket because it might help in generating potential alternate solutions for the downstream objective. A very common reason for web proxy servers is circumvention of the same origin policy (CORS), but that doesn't apply to the WebSocket protocol. Are you trying to conceal your IP address and can't use a VPN? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to conceal my IP address and I can't use a VPN since I want to rotate my IP addresses. I generally have no problem with doing that in node. But I am new to Deno and have no idea how to do it there, since the deeper I dive into the code the more confusing it gets, and eventually it ends in switching to Rust. In the node ws package it's simple. You can just switch the standard HTTP agent with a proxy agent. But I cannot find something similar in the deno websocket.

Comment: So, to be clear, are you asking (1) “How do I build a WebSocket proxy server in Deno?” or (2) “How do I initiate a client WebSocket connection to an existing proxy server?”

Comment: I want to connect to an existing Websocket Server but using a Proxy

Comment: So you already have access to a proxy server capable of proxying WebSocket connections and you're wondering about no. 2?

Comment: Yes, I have access to a proxy server capable of proxying WebSocket connections

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is not yet possible in Deno. Here's the related GitHub tracking issue: [denoland/deno#10743](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/10743)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work for WebSockets, it's not explicitly mentioned, but Deno supports proxies via environment variables, see https://deno.land/manual@v1.25.1/linking_to_external_code/proxies

If you try it out I would be interested in knowing if it worked or not.

Something else (instead of your `createRequire` import) you can do since Deno version 1.25 is directly importing npm packages like this:

`import * as <whatever> from 'npm:<packagename>'`

although this is currently flagged as unstable and therefore requires you to run your code with `--unstable`.

Comment: Thanks for the import advice. I didnt know that. But unfortunatly as @jsejcksn already wrote above the enviroment variables do not work for websockets.